# Code Not Tracking Email Enquiries In Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion, google-analytics

I am trying to get email enquiries submitted through the website to show up in Analytics as a tracked event. 
This client has multiple domains so we are tracking which email enquiry came from which site.

This is the code created so far. (please note we use coldfusion to pull from our CMS system)

```
<!-- Analytics Tracking Code-->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '<cfif isdefined ("getsite.contact") AND getsite.contact NEQ      "">#getsite.contact#<cfelse>UA-109409-1</cfif>']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  (function() {
     var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-  analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>



<!--Email Tracking Code in Analytics -->

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('form').submit(function(event){
        //if analytics object exists
        if(window._gat){
            event.preventDefault();
            optinForm = this;
            _gaq.push(['_set','hitCallback', function(){
                                            optinForm.submit();
                                         }]);
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Email Enquiry', 'Form Submitted', '#getsite.domain#']);
        }
        //if no analytics object, service as normal
    });
});

</script>
```

Any assistance would be great.

Comment: What does this have to do with ColdFusion?

Comment: <cfif isdefined ("getsite.contact") AND getsite.contact NEQ      "">#getsite.contact#<cfelse>UA-109409-1</cfif> is a way of getting the UA code entered into the CMS in our sytsems. This is the only ColdFusion within the code.

Comment: I suggest removing the cf code from the example and just try with hard coded values. Will make it easier to test and read the example. Once you have it working you can make it dynamic.